# rename file name from middle of extension in Linux using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, file-rename

I wanted to rename the below file name.

"PHOTO..CS_DEVELOPEMENT.20220317182718.C201.25332.DST.STD.gz"

file should be trimmed like below.

"PHOTO..CS_DEVELOPEMENT.20220317182718.C201.gz"

I have tried with this option "filename=$i ; mv $filename ${filename%.*}" but it didn't work, I wanted to this via bash script in Linux any help appreciated

I have list the file file using `ls -lrt | grep -E "c201" | awk '{print $8}'`
using for loop .

"for i in `ls -lrt | grep -E "C20..." | awk '{print $8}'`; do filename=$i ; mv $filename ${filename%.gz}; done"

not working it only trim the last extension.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [don’t parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!

Comment: This question is likely better fit for Unix & Linux SE or SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Something like `for filename in *C20* ; do mv "${filename}" "${filename%.*.*.*.*}.gz" ; done`?

Comment: …or use `rename`.

Comment: @Biffen thanks a lot it is working thank you for your very quick help :)